# "null" is included in the jar file name after doing a maven install for the spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, executable-jar

I am new to Spring boot and just getting started. I have created a new spring boot application and I see error on the first line of pom.xml.
I have gone through some blogs and decided to proceed further with Maven build. I have done Maven clean ans Maven install. The Build was success after maven install and a jar file is created in the target folder. 
However, there is null included in the name of the jar file created. I am assuming that I might have missed something in the pom.xml.

Can someone help me understand what would be the naming convention of the jar file from the pom.xml.

Why would the build be successful even when there is an error showing on the first line of pom.xml?

Thanks a lot in advance.

POM.xml

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>my-sample-module</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>my-sample-module</name>
<description>Kafka Module for creating messages</description>
```

Jar file created :

my-sample-module-1.0.0null.jar

Comment: any plugins you are using to create the jar ?

Comment: @QuickSilver - Thanks a lot for your quick turnaround. Able to resolve the issue. I have fiven <finalName> under build and I have not given the build number. <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}${build.number}</finalName>

Answer (score 1):

Posting the answer so it might be helpful for someone-

```
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}${build.number}</finalName>
```

This is how the jar would be created. In the above example, I have not given the build.number under properties tag in the pom.xml. So the build.number is being read as a null value while building the jar file.

It can be anything which we can define under properties tag in pom.xml.

Or a more simple solution to avoid the null in the jar file

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
```

Comment: The build.number does simply not exist in maven...? Where has that being defined?

Comment: It does not have to be build.number necessarily. It could be any tag name which we can define under    <properties>. Updated above answer accordingly.